# Can you make Network Requests from a Heroku Application?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have not been able to find any information on this without reading through all of the docs.
Basically, are network requests to an outside source free or possibly not available at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests are not blocked and Heroku doesn't charge on a per-request basis. Costs are determined by the type of instance you provision on the platform.

Comment: I could not find any information on network requests in the [pricing section](https://www.heroku.com/pricing). If I wanted to test functionality, could I send network requests for no cost using the Free tier?

Comment: Yes, the Free tier is Free.